# create relation when node exist else create a new node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 types of node staff and client where staff has 
StaffList

```
{
  "name": "vipul",
  "cprNumber": 121
}
,{
  "name": "amit",
  "cprNumber": 123
}
```

ClientList

```
{
  "property1": "pptVal",
  "cprNumber": 121
}
```

now I want to create a relationship between these 2 nodes like in the first case the CPR number is matched so a relationship creates "BELONGS_TO" for vipul, but since no, any node exists for amit's cpr number so a new node needs to be created and a relationship to be created.

Comment: Are you try `merge`?

Comment: if match found then merge else create a new node and add the relation

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UPxLw 
Please look reference Image

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve your goal using [MERGE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/):

```
// Match Vipul and Amit nodes
MATCH (a:Client)
// Match :ClientList node when it has cprNumber = a.cprNumber.
// When no node is matched, create it.
MERGE (b:ClientList {cprNumber : a.cprNumber})
// Create :BELONGS_TO relationship
CREATE (a)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(b)
```

Comment: hi @bruno-peres 
unfortunately the client node is not equal to staff list so somehow using case(or other methods) we need to create a node (of client) if no node availabe with that CPR_NUMBER